# How to pass Arrays as arguments to a function in Scala?

Tags: scala

forgive if this is too basic of a question,I'm pretty new to scala and been stuck at this particularly.

What I'm trying to achieve is,to have a function which takes an array as arguments,like so :

```
 evenOdd(1,2,3,4,5,6);  //where evenOdd is my function
```

The function definition looks like :

```
def evenOdd(x : Array[Int] = new Array[Int](6)){

}
```

It throws an error that too many arguments for the function.How can I achieve passing multiple array integers as fixed size in the function ?

Answer (score 9):

Either pass an `Array` to `evenOdd`:

```
evenOdd(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

or define `evenOdd` as:

```
def evenOdd(x: Int*) = {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were passing a varargs ([read more about it here](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/varargs.html)). However, your function `evenOdd` accepts an array of integers.

You have two ways to solve this:

1. Make `evenOdd` function to accept varargs of integer. The drawback of this is that you cannot assign a default value for this:

   `def evenOdd(x : Int*)`
2. Don't change the input paramters of `evenOdd`, but pass in an array of integer instead:

   `evenOdd(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6))`

Comment: #1 doesn't compile because varargs parameter cannot be assigned a default value.

Answer (score 1):

> Check is an example for the passing array as an argument

```
object ArrayRotation {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

    call(arr)
  }
  def call(arr: Array[Int]) {
    for (i <- 0 to 1) {
      for (j <- 0 to arr.length - 2) {
        var temp = arr(j)
        arr(j) = arr(j + 1)
        arr(j + 1) = temp

      }

    }
    for (i <- 0 to arr.length - 1) {
      print(arr(i))
    }
  }

}
```